# subset data with timestamp irrespective of date in R

Tags: r, dataframe, timestamp

The Dataset

```
head(data)
               Date   OPEN
2015-11-30 10:00:00 951.15
2015-11-30 10:30:00 949.90
2015-11-30 11:00:00 943.45
2015-11-30 11:30:00 944.30
2015-11-30 12:00:00 942.00
2015-11-30 12:30:00 940.60
2015-01-01 10:00:00 951.15
2015-01-01 10:30:00 949.90
2015-01-02 10:30:00 943.45
2015-01-02 11:30:00 944.30
2015-01-03 10:00:00 943.45
2015-01-03 10:30:00 943.45
2015-01-03 11:30:00 944.30
2015-01-06 10:00:00 942.00
2015-01-06 10:30:00 940.60
2015-01-06 11:00:00 940.60
2015-01-06 11:30:00 942.00

str(data)
'data.frame':   32023 obs. of  2 variables:
$ Date      : POSIXct, format: "2015-11-30 10:00:00" "2015-11-30 10:30:00" "2015-11-30 11:00:00" ...
 $ OPEN      : num  951 950 943 944 942 ...
```

Hi,
Dataframe is mentioned above. I want to extract OPEN prices with timestamps `10:00 and 10:30` for all the dates available. I only need to keep timestamps `10:00 to 10:30` in filter condition `irrespective of dates`. Please suggest in `R`.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `format` the 'Date' to extract the `HH:MM` part, use `%in%` to get a logical  `vector` and `subset` based on that.

```
subset(data, format(Date, "%H:%M") %in% c("10:00", "10:30"), select="OPEN")
#     OPEN
#1  951.15
#2  949.90
#7  951.15
#8  949.90
#9  943.45
#11 943.45
#12 943.45
#14 942.00
#15 940.60
```

If it is `between` those intervals

```
library(chron)
subset(data, between(times(format(Date, "%H:%M:%S")) , 
                              times("10:00:00"), times("10:30:00")))
```

Comment: using chron looks just perfect. have to check it. thanks.

Comment: This subset command was working that time. But now this is not working. Showing this error - Error in UseMethod("between") : 
  no applicable method for 'between' applied to an object of class "times". Dataset is same. Can you please suggest.

Comment: @Zico `between` function can be found in `dplyr` and `data.table`.  So, you may have to load either of these packages and it should work.

Comment: yes, I have checked and loaded both, but still it is failing. is there any recent change in packages? do you have any idea about it?

Comment: I am using dplyr_0.5.0. and R 3.3. 0

Comment: you are right. I updated the dplyr and now it's working again. thanks. I missed it.

Comment: @Zico I also had similar problems with functions in dplyr.  Sometimes, functions that worked previously will not work, Recently, somebody said that we had to `ungroup` for something to work, but in 0.5.0, it worked without it.

Comment: can you please give me that discussion link about "ungroup"? if only it is with you by any chance.

Comment: @Zico It was commented by somebody in one of my solutions.  I forgot which one is that, but it should be within a week or so.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `lubridate` package to make a friendly subset:

```
library(lubridate)
res <- subset(data, minute(Date) <=30 & hour(Date) == 10)
```

Comment: in this case i have to first do like this: minute(Date) >=30 & hour(Date) >= 10 and then again do like that on output of first eqn: minute(Date) <=30 & hour(Date) <= 15. it's not one liner but has rescued me today.